# ID might not have been initialised with @GeneratedValue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pojo, lombok

I am making a RESTful API using Spring Boot and the spring data JPA. One of my model classes looks like so:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private final long id;

    private final Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    private Object bar;

    public Foo(Object bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.date = new Date();
    }
}
```

However, it says that the id has not been initialised (I assume because it is not in my custom constructor) even though it is annotated with `@GeneratedValue`. How should I work around this?

Is there a better way of creating a POJO object?

Comment: Since you have used the final for the id field. Hence it is asking you to initialize it. If you remove final keyword then it should work.

Comment: @NitinBisht but then the `@Data` annotation will create a Setter for it, which I do not want to happen

Comment: You can use @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE) @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)